# $M$ being the direct sum of submodules $(M_i)_{i \in I}$ is equivalent to a certain map (between $\operatorname{Hom}$-sets) being an isomorphism.

Tags: commutative-algebra, category-theory, modules

I am currently trying to prove a remark in *Bosch: Algebraic Geometry and Commutative Algebra* (chapter 1.4):

> Consider a family $(M_i)_{i \in I}$ of submodules in $M$. Then the inclusion maps $\iota_i \colon M_i \hookrightarrow M$ determine an $R$-module homomorphism
> $$ \Phi \colon \operatorname{Hom}_R(M,N) \longrightarrow \prod_{i \in I}  \operatorname{Hom}_R(M_i,N), \qquad \varphi \longmapsto (\varphi \circ \iota_i)_{i \in I} .$$ It is easily seen that $\Phi$ is an isomorphism for *all* R-modules $N$ **if and only if**  $M$ is the direct sum of the submodules $M_i \subseteq M$.

I managed to prove the if-part of the claimed equivalence but am struggling with the **only-if**-part.

So let $(M_i)_{i \in I}$ be a family of submodules of an $R$-module $M$ and suppose $\Phi$ is an isomorphism for all $R$-modules $N$. We want to show that $ \sum_{i \in I} M_i = M $ and that this sum is in fact direct.

We can choose $N := \hat\oplus_{i \in I} M_i $, by which I denote the **external** direct sum of the $M_i$. Consider the family $(\tau_j)_{j \in I}$ of canonical homomorphisms $\tau_j \colon M_j \hookrightarrow \hat\oplus_{i \in I} M_i$ (with $\tau_j(m) := (\delta_{ji} m)_{i \in I}$). Since $\Phi$ is bijective, there is exactly one homomorphism $\varphi \colon M \rightarrow \hat\oplus_{i \in I} M_i$ with $ \Phi(\varphi) = (\tau_j)_{j \in I} $, i.e. with $\varphi \vert_{M_j} = \tau_j$ for all $j \in I$.

Now let $\sum_{i \in I} m_i \in \sum_{i \in I} M_i $ be arbitrary with $\sum_{i \in I} m_i = 0$. Then
$$ (0)_{i \in I} = \varphi(0) = \varphi\left( \sum_{i \in I} m_i \right) = \sum_{i \in I} \varphi(m_i) = \sum_{i \in I} \tau_i(m_i) = (m_i)_{i \in I}, $$
which implies $m_i = 0$ for all $i \in I$. Thus we have shown that the sum $\sum_{i \in I} M_i$ is indeed direct.

**This is my problem:** In order to show that  $\sum_{i \in I} M_i$ is already the whole of $M$, I now wanted to take an arbitrary $m \in M$, map it to some $\varphi(m) = (m_i)_{i \in I} \in \hat\oplus_{i \in I} M_i $ and then claim $ m = \sum_{i \in I} m_i$ ($\in \sum_{i \in I} M_i$). If we knew for example that $ \varphi $ was injective, this would follow, since both $ \varphi(m) = (m_j)_{j \in I} $ and $$\varphi\left(\sum_{i \in I} m_i\right) = \sum_{i \in I} \varphi(m_i) = \sum_{i \in I} \varphi\vert_{M_i}(m_i) = \sum_{i \in I} \tau_i(m_i) = \sum_{i \in I} (\delta_{ij}m_i)_{j \in I} = (m_j)_{j \in I}. $$
I am struggling to show the injectivity of $\varphi$. I also have not really used that $\Phi$ is injective anywhere yet. What am I missing? Any hints much appreciated. :-)

N.B.: In the book, the remark serves as a prelude to the universal mapping property of direct sums. So I do not want to use this universal property at this stage.

**Edit:** Changed the proof for the directness of the sum $\sum_{i \in I} M_i$ due to a comment of Daniel Schepler.

Comment: Hint: if $S = \sum_{i\in I} M_i$, then you have two maps $\pi, 0 : M \to M / S$ which will end up giving the same image in $\prod_{i\in I} \operatorname{Hom}_R(M_i, M / S)$.

Comment: Also, to get a direct sum, don't you really need to show that $M_i \cap (\sum_{j \in I \setminus \{ i \}} M_j) = 0$?

Comment: @DanielSchepler: Oh, you are right. I somehow wrongly assumed it would be enough to show $M_i \cap M_j = \{0\}$ for $i \neq j$. I changed the proof for the directness of the sum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\hom}{\operatorname{Hom}}$I know you don't want it just yet but for future reference here is the 'easy' way (the key observation being the second isomorphism):

$$\hom_R(M,N)\cong\prod_{i\in I}\hom_R(M_i,N)\cong\hom_R\left(\bigoplus_{i\in I}M_i,N\right)$$Naturally in $N$; use Yoneda lemma to conclude. We can make that more concrete: plug in $N=M$, plug in $\mathrm{Id}_M$ into the left hand side, find a morphism $\bigoplus_{i\in I}M_i\to N$ in the right hand side. Then plug in $N=\bigoplus_{i\in I}M_i$ in the right hand side and $\mathrm{Id}_{\bigoplus_{i\in I}M_i}$, find a morphism $M\to\bigoplus_{i\in I}M_i$ in the left hand side. It will follow these morphisms are mutually inverse so that $M\cong\bigoplus_{i\in I}M_i$ (via the inclusions $M_i\to M)$. Here, in the abstract proof, $\bigoplus$ is denoting "external" direct sum but since each $M_i\subseteq M$ we'd get $M=\bigoplus_{i\in I}M_i$ internally.

You seem to have been following along these lines already. In the below I instead use $\iota_i$ for the map $M_i\hookrightarrow\bigoplus_{i\in I}M_i$ (for *internal* direct sum).

Define $\varphi:M\to\bigoplus_{i\in I}M_i$, as you have done, through $\Phi^{-1}((\tau_i)_{i\in I})$. Conclude from the existence of $\varphi$ that the $M_\bullet$ are internally linearly disjoint. Redefine $\bigoplus_{i\in I}M_i$ to be the internal direct sum and redefine $\varphi$ accordingly by replacing the $\tau_i$ with the $\iota_i$, so that $\varphi$ maps $M$ to a submodule of $M$. We want to procure an inverse to $\varphi$. Well, of course there is the submodule inclusion $\psi:\bigoplus_{i\in I}M_i\hookrightarrow M$.

By construction, $\varphi\psi$ is the identity; $\varphi$'s restriction to every $M_i$ is by definition the inclusion $M_i\hookrightarrow M$.

For the converse $\psi\varphi:M\to M$, this is the identity if and only if $\Phi(\psi\varphi)$ is $(M_i\hookrightarrow M)_{i\in I}$ since we have assumed $\Phi$ is an isomorphism. On $m\in M_i$, $\psi\varphi(m)=\psi\varphi(\iota_i(m))=\psi\circ\Phi(\varphi)_i(m)=\psi(\iota_i(m))=m$ as required.

It follows that the internal sum $\bigoplus_{i\in I}M_i$ is literally equal to $M$.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. I appreciate you having given a more categorical approach as well, though I do not fully understand it (yet). :-)

Answer (score 1):

Though @FShrike gave a perfect answer to my question, I wanted to complete my proof as an exercise. (But I will essentially only reproduce their thoughts – so nothing really new here.)

Let $\varphi \colon M \rightarrow \hat\oplus_{i \in I} M_i$ be defined as in my question above. We want to show that $\varphi$ is injective, thus completing the proof.

Let $\psi \colon \hat\oplus_{i \in I} M_i \rightarrow M$ be defined by $\psi((m_i)_{i \in I}) := \sum_{i \in I} m_i$, which clearly is a homomorphism.

Next, we can choose $N := M$ and consider $\psi \circ \varphi \in \operatorname{Hom}_R(M,M)$. For arbitrary $i \in I$ and $m_i \in M_i$ we then get
$$ (\psi \circ \varphi \circ \iota_i)(m_i) = (\psi \circ \tau_i)(m_i) = \psi((\delta_{ij}m_i)_{j \in I}) = \sum_{j \in I} \delta_{ij}m_i = m_i = (\operatorname{id}_M \circ \iota_i)(m_i)$$
which shows $\Phi(\psi \circ \varphi) = (\psi \circ \varphi \circ \iota_i)_{i \in I} = (\operatorname{id}_M \circ \iota_i)_{i \in I} = \Phi(\operatorname{id}_M)$. Since we supposed $\Phi$ to be an isomorphism, this implies $\psi \circ \varphi = \operatorname{id}_M$, hence $\varphi$ is indeed injective.

Comment: Nice :)${}{}{}$